# Optimizing function parameters vs optimizing perturbations of function parameters

Tags: derivatives, optimization, lie-algebras

I'm a bit new to optimization methods, and I noticed in some definitions like [Gauss-Newton wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm) the cost derivatives (Jacobian or other) are w.r.t the parameters themselves. However, in other contexts such as the answer to [another question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/182940/955212), the optimization derivatives are defined w.r.t. to the infinitesmal change evaluated at 0. Conceptually, they seem similar, however, from an implementation standpoint there is a large difference. For example given the context of the problem of the second link, evaluating derivative of a function of rotations w.r.t. axis-angle is a cumbersome equation, while evaluating the derivative w.r.t. to the infinitesmal axis-angle change is as simple as the generating function in the Lie space.

More fundamentally, is there a difference between optimizing a cost w.r.t. to some variables and optimizing a cost w.r.t. to the perturbation of some variables or is it just a math trick exploited depending on optimization context?